# Whats wrong with my Eclipse or phone?

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

When I connect my phone when Eclipse is running, in the LogCat it continues to write something without end, and prints some error messages all the time "Fatal signal something", whats wrong? Here's part of the log, it's still printing and doesn't sime like it will stop soon

http://pastebin.com/4Z58CiGm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all logs from system apps and processes, and you can safely ignore them.

You should tag all the statements from your app using:

```
Log.d("MyAwesomeTag", "Message");
```

Then you can filter them using `tag:MyAwesomeTag` and ignore everything that isn't yours

Comment: Yes, but why it isn't stopping, the log will go on whole night if I leave it

Comment: @SartherisStormhammer Because your phone is switched on, and all these processes are active.

Comment: ohhh, so you mean it do it all the time? maybe I haven't noticed it because the LogCat wasnt't always switched to

Comment: @SartherisStormhammer Yes, these logs are made 24x7, even when your phone isn't plugged in.